# How to mock method inside method in scala object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to use a simple example for my problem.

I have a below trait:

```scala
trait ReaderTrait {

 def readTable(tableName:String, closingDate: String)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {

sparkSession.read.table(
      tableName
    ).filter(col("closingDate") === closingDate)
 
 }

def read(fullTable:String, closingDate: String)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame

}
```

I have below Object:

```scala
object Reader extends  ReaderTrait
 {

override final def read(fullTable: String, closingDate: String)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame =
 {

  readTable(fullTable: String, closingDate: String)
//.filter..
//I have business logic here which I want to test, I want to mock only readTable
  }

}
```

Now I want to mock only the `readTable` method in Object.

I have a Test class:

```scala
class ReaderTest extends FeatureSpec with MockitoSugar {

 scenario("first") {

//sample dataframe1 created ......

    val mockTrait = mock[Reader.type ] 
    when(mockTrait.readTable("abc", "sss")(spark)) thenReturn (dataframe1)
    val result = mockTrait.read("abc", "sss")(spark)
    result.show()
  }
}
```

After running the above test class, it's giving me the below error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.

Please help me to resolve this situation; I have to mock the `readTable` method in read method in object without making any changes to existing code.

Comment: Please provide more detailed stacktrace. We need to know where the null is being passed.

Comment: I have updated the above example

Answer (score 2):

Many problems here:

- You cannot mock objects.
  `mock[Reader.type]` does not make sense. You could mock the *trait* with `mock[ReaderTrait]` though.
- Mock doesn't work the way you seem to think.

If you have `class A { def foo = ""; def bar = foo }`, and then you do

```
    val m = mock[A]
    when(m.foo).thenReturn("baz")
    val result = m.bar
```

the value of `result` will *not* be "baz" it will be `null`. Why? Because `m` is a *mock* – a dummy object, with *all* of the methods stubbed out. `m.bar` does *not* call `foo`, because it is a stub, it just returns `null`.

There is a way to stub only some methods of a class, and have others keep original behavior. If you'd like to learn more about it, look up the concept of a `spy` (you would do `spy(new A)` instead of `mock[A]`). I will not get into this here, because *it is not a good practice* to use spies. Which brings me to my third point ...

- You should not stub methods of the class you are testing. When you need to, it is a symptom of your class design violating the single responsibility principle, which is not a good thing.

The proper way of writing your test in this case would be isolate the `readTable` "provider" class from the functionality you are testing.
For example:

```
trait TableReader { 
  def readTable(table:String, date: String)(implicit s: SparkSession) = 
    s.read.table(table).filter(col("closingDate") === date) 
}
object TableReader extends TableReader

class Reader(val tr: TableReader) { 
   def read(table: String, date: String)(implicit s: SparkSession) = 
      tr.readTable(table, date)
}
object Reader extends Reader(TableReader)
```

Now you can test your `Reader` class with something like:

```
    val tr = mock[TableReader]
    wen(tr.readTable(any, any)(any)).thenReturn(dataframe1)
    val reader = new Reader(tr)
    reader.read("foo", "bar")(spark) shouldBe dataframe1
    verify(tr).readTable("foo", "bar")(spark)
```

This will work, but kinda unclear *what* it is you are trying to test here.
You are not testing `readTable` because you stubbed it out. And there is no logic in `read`, so nothing to test there.

I would suggest to move the filtering logic out from `TableReader` into `Reader`, that would make for a cleaner separation of responsibilities between the two classes: one is responsible for fetching data from the table, and the other applies filtering and other business logic:

```
trait TableReader { 
  def readTable(t: String)(implicit s: SparkSession) = s.read.table(t)
}
class Reader(tr: TableReader) {
  def read(table: String, date: String)(implicit s: SparkSession) = 
     tr.readTable(table).filter(col("closingDate") === date) 
}
```

This gives you an ability to write meaningful tests, like:

```
  reader.read("foo", "bar")(spark)
    .select("closingDate")
    .as[String]
    .collect
    .toList shouldBe List("bar", "bar", "bar")
```

(basically, checking that the filter for `closingDate === "bar"` was properly applied to the dataframe)

The idea here is that *you do not need to test* `TableReader`, as there is no any business logic there, it is only a simple wrapper around spark, so you can stub it out easily.

And the `Reader` class is only concerned about business logic that you *do* want to test, and does not know anything about where the actual data comes from, so you don't need to stub any of its methods, just supply a mock provider of the data (`mock[TableReader]`).

Comment: Hello @Dima, I have some business logic in method read which i want to test, i want to mock only readtable.